# shuffle array after index

Tags: swift, shuffle, swift4.2

I am trying to shuffle array after specific index, i did with splitting/joined mechanism, but, is there any efficient way?

**Ex:**

```
var arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]


arr.shuffle(after index:4)
print(arr) -> //[0,1,2,3,4,7,9,8,6]

arr.shuffle(after index:0)
print(arr) -> //[0,3,2,1,4,9,8,6,8]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`shuffle()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mutablecollection/2996411-shuffle) is a  method of the `MutableCollection` protocol, therefore it can be applied to an array *slice.* Example:

```
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
arr[5...].shuffle() // Shuffle elements from index 5 to the end
print(arr) // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 7, 5, 9]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
extension Array {
    mutating func shuffle(fromIndex:Int) {
        self[fromIndex...].shuffle()
    }

    func shuffled(fromIndex:Int) -> [Element]{
        return self[..<fromIndex] + self[fromIndex...].shuffled()
    }
}

var arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
arr.shuffle(fromIndex: 4) // 0,1,2,3,x,x,x,x,x,x - x - any of the value of 4...9

let arr2 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
var arr3 = arr2.shuffled(fromIndex: 4)
```

For `mutating func shuffle(fromIndex:Int)` to work array must be a `var`. This will not work with `let`. `func shuffled(fromIndex:Int) -> [Any]` - for a shuffled copy of let array

Comment: An array extension method which references (and mutates) a global variable? – You probably meant something like `self[fromIndex...].shuffle()`. Also note that your method does not `return` anything.

Comment: Also, I am wondering how to achieve this if arr is a let constant.

Comment: i think for `let` it is not possible!!

Comment: @SPatel - yes exactly, but can return a mutated copy of its, with desired shuffling.

Comment: it's `shuffled`!

Comment: Returning `[Any]` is bad because all type information is lost. Better return `[Element]`.

Comment: Your method signature is declared as mutating and returning void but in method body you are returning an array instead of assigning a new value to self

Comment: @LeoDabus: `return self[fromIndex...].shuffle()` does mutate self and returns void – of course the `return` statement is completely unnecessary (and confusing) at this point.

Comment: Yeah, that there by mistake. It's ment for the second function. Corrected, thanks for finding it.